# how to setup a node project on iis 10

Tags: node.js, iis, hosting

I'm new to Node so, currently i'm starting server from cmd but, i want make it from iss so, i can use vhost and its starts automatically even if system restart unexpectedly. But, i didn't find any helpful information to setup on iis10 and i only seen old stuff for iis7/8.

I tried to install iisnode from web platform installer even its older(clearly, mentioned its for iis6/7 only) and configured web.config as following but, its not working

```
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />"
```

so, if any one have idea please, give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Linux hosting is both cheaper and better for NodeJS applications.

Comment: try to set the handler in web.config file: `<handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>`  [link1](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki/iisnode-releases#new-in-0221) , [link2](https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html)

Comment: @LexLi Already, i have windows ec2 instance so, i want to host there

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Already, i tried both the links but, they are referring to iis7/8 only. I need iisnode for iis10

Comment: IIS 7/8/10 are equivalent. But since iisnode is almost a dead project, your choice to run such apps on IIS/Windows is doomed to be troublesome.